# Sequence data tracking in Redshift table

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I have a data like given image.I want to track the all group changes based on reportdate  sequence.

Ex: If take 'A'  data should balance=1.5 and date='9/30/2015' and 'C' balance=2.05 and date='12/01/2017'.

[image]

I have tried with sql but it tracked all the changes like A to B , A to C and A to D any method to resolve this script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(balance) over (partition by number order by date) as next_balance
from t
```

Comment: Thanks Gorden, But My problem is taking group in consecutive date sequence!